# DevComponent in vb.net how to remove

Tags: vb.net

I installed devcomponents before my pc got formatted. So I have a new pc now and I cant install devcomponents again because I lost my installer. While I'm opening my vb.net project I can't open the designer because of devcomponents not installed. The error says.

Type 'Devcomponents.DotNetBar.ButtonX' is not defined

What I want to do is I manually remove the properties of devcomponents and convert it to the default buttons, label or etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and do a clean install of Visual Studio 2015. I wouldn't suggest tinkering with its files like that, this is probably the quickest and easiest thing to do.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I use DevComponents a lot, and really the only way i can think you would be able to remove everything related to it, its a little lengthy of a process, but it should work, and make sure you make a back-up of the project before you do this in case anything gets mistakenly removed, that you dont want to lose, that way you always have something to fall back on.

**Step 1.)** Go into the projects properties (Project > "Project Name" Properties)

**Step 2.)** Go to references and remove the references that have to do with the devcomponents dll's.

**Step 3.)** Open the form or forms that contains their controls, but not the form itself you need to open the designer code for each of the forms (in the solution explorer panel click the collapse arrow next to the form with the controls on it, and double click InitializeComponent(), that will open up the designer code for you.)

**Step 4.)** Only Do this step if you also used their office form there should be a piece of code that says `Inherits` on the 3rd line if its set to `inherit Devcomponents.dotnetbar etc...` then you need to change the form to inherit back to this `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

**Step 5.)** Continuing while still being in the designer code you will have to look through it and make sure that all of the references towards creating any tool that you used from devcomponents is removed, or like you wanted to change them to the default controls included you can change the code to make them be created as a regular control instead of being created as a devcomponent control

***Step 5 Example.)*** using a button as example... simply by changing this: `Me.ButtonX8 = New DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonX()` to this `Me.ButtonX8 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()`

Ultimately though, if you don't mind remaking, and fixing what code handles what buttons though, i would recommend just removing the references completely that way when you re-open the form in designer all of them will be gone and you can just remake the buttons, i say this because a lot of the controls from devcomponents have a lot of their own properties so just changing them will require a lot of trial and error to figure out which properties don't belong and will cause an error when trying to run. But with enough effort all the stuff from devcomponents can be removed, or replaced... will just take a bit of effort to do, it will also need to be done to all forms made which have their controls on them.

This is the way i know, if anyone else knows a better, and or faster way of accomplishing this feel free to comment.